# SQLite : Count function returning [object Database] (JS)

Tags: javascript, sqlite, discord.js

**Here is my code:**

```
            var query = 'SELECT COUNT(Tag) FROM bugs';

            var tagnow = db.get(query, (err) => {
                if (err){
                    console.log(err);
                    return;
                };
```

**console.log(tagnow):** [object Database]

**What I want it to return:** Integer value showing total number of rows under 'Tag'

Thank you for your time.

Comment: "*of columns named 'Tag'*" - don't you mean "*of rows in the 'Tag' column*"?

Comment: oops, yes that is what I mean

Comment: What type is your `db`?

Comment: it's OPEN_READWRITE

Comment: Well I can't find documentation for the method `.get` you're using that's why I asked for `db`'s type (can you add the code where you set it like `db = ...`?)

Comment: db = new sqlite.Database('./bugs.db', sqlite.OPEN_READWRITE ); (this has worked before)

Comment: My bet is that `db.get(...)` gives you the row and you need to get the cell value. By *this has worked before*, do you mean that you managed to get a cell value with the code in your question?

Comment: I meant that `db.get` gave me a cell value. Shouldn't count function return an integer?

Comment: Rafalon, I think I've figured it out, Thanks a lot for your time and responding ;)

Comment: Well you're welcome, I didn't do much though tbh ^^